# JAX-RS 2.0 change default implementation

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm trying to use RESTEasy as JAX-RS 2.0 client implementation. The problem is that I got runtime exception:

```
06-28 13:29:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(5745): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
06-28 13:29:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:103)
```

So the `newBuilder()` method is searching for `JerseyClientBuilder` if I understand it correct. How can I tell the system to use RESTEasy instead?

Comment: The answer by Carlo seems reasonable. Did you try it out? Did it resolve your problem? If so, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, JAX-RS relies on the Service Provider convention. 
On the first lines of the `newBuilder` method you can read:

```
 Object delegate = FactoryFinder.find(JAXRS_DEFAULT_CLIENT_BUILDER_PROPERTY,
   JAXRS_DEFAULT_CLIENT_BUILDER);
```

Where `JAXRS_DEFAULT_CLIENT_BUILDER_PROPERTY` is `"javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder"`

In turn, `FactoryFinder` looks

- first for the class name into `META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder`
- then in the property `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder` into `${java.home}/lib/jaxrs.properties`
- finally into the System property `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder`.

So, to use RESTEasy, you should create a file

```
META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder
```

with the text:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder
```

which is the class name of the RESTEasy `ClientBuilder`

Comment: You can achieve the same by setting system property: `System.setProperty(ClientBuilder.JAXRS_DEFAULT_CLIENT_BUILDER_PROPERTY, "org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder");` or by creating a file `$java.home/lib/jaxrs.properties`

Comment: Just a note that unlike `java.util.ServiceLoader`, the JAX-RS FactoryFinder does **not** allow #-comments in the `META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder` file. Discovered the painful way.