# ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl cannot be found in OSGi bundle which has embedded cxf dependencies

Tags: java, maven, osgi, cxf, jax-rs

This is relate to the [jax-rs-2-0-change-default-implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366266/jax-rs-2-0-change-default-implementation)
I'm having an OSGi bundle which consist of cxf 2.7.8 as well as openejb. cxf dependencies are added as embedded dependencies.

When I try to deploy a webapp I'm getting the below exception.
When I set the system property when starting the server as `-Djavax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate=org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.RuntimeDelegateImpl` this can be solved.

But in the above link it says that when I have the `META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate` file with the content as `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.RuntimeDelegateImpl` this can be solved.

In my OSGi bundle that file exist in the `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.8.jar` But this jar is embedded in the OSGi bundle seems that is not getting pick correctly. I tried to add the same file to the OSGi bundle `META-INF/services` but it didn't work either.

Can someone tell me is there a way to get rid of this without manually setting the system property?
`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.<clinit>(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newInstance(Proxy.java:764)  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:755)     at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRSService$ContextBean.<init>(CxfRSService.java:192)  at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRSService.contextCDIIntegration(CxfRSService.java:111)   at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRSService.integrateCDIAndJaxRsInjections(CxfRSService.java:100)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$MethodInvocation.invoke(ObserverManager.java:400)    at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager.doFire(ObserverManager.java:111)     at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager.fireEvent(ObserverManager.java:100)  at org.apache.openejb.loader.SystemInstance.fireEvent(SystemInstance.java:134)  at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:150)    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)  at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:838)     at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:644)     at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1250)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.wso2.carbon.javaee.tomee.ASTomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(ASTomcatWebAppBuilder.java:127)    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)   at org.wso2.carbon.javaee.tomee.ASGlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(ASGlobalListenerSupport.java:74)     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5412)    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:345)    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:190)    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:257)    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWarWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:207)     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleHotDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:174)   at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.deploy(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:139)    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deployThisWebApp(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:204)  at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deploy(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:111)    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer.WebappDeployer.deploy(WebappDeployer.java:42)    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)   at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)   at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)   at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:135)     at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.deployServices(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:567)  at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.DeploymentServerStartupObserver.completingServerStartup(DeploymentServerStartupObserver.java:51)   at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.notifyBefore(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:235)   at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.completeInitialization(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:185)     at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.serviceChanged(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:288)     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)   at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.registerThrottlingAgent(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:123)  at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.activate(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:100)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)   at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:517)     at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:91)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl cannot be found by tomee_1.7.2.SNAPSHOT_wso2v1  at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:151)   at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:119)    at javax.ws.rs.core.EntityTag.<clinit>(EntityTag.java:56)   ... 131 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl cannot be found by tomee_1.7.2.SNAPSHOT_wso2v1  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)  at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:114)    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:207)   at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:134)   ... 133 more`

Answer (score 9):

Was able to find the answer here: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSAS-1870

Basically you need to add a system property for setting the default delegate:

javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate=org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.RuntimeDelegateImpl

Answer (score 9):

If you are using

> import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

then add the following dependency in your 'pom.xml' file. It worked for me..

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is for just general Spring, not for fixing other frameworks using JAX-RS

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, and I never said anything that contradicts it!

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar issue with Spring Boot 2, Jersey and Eureka. I was able to work around by adding a variation of mkwyche's answer:

```
-Djavax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate=com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with Jax-RS.
To fix the problem add this dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42667182/) answer is correct, but for the gradle users out there, add this to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
}
```